# Log access to environment variables in windows

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have a legacy application (for windows 98) which searches for configuration files using the some paths it finds in the environment variables.

The workstation where it was installed was recently formatted and I forgot to save the environment variables and don't know their names.

Is there a way to monitor what the application tries to read from the environment ? 
I would need something like processmonitor from former sysinternals...

Comment: If you can kinda remember what they are you could peruse Process Explorer's "Strings" option (reads literals from the image/process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The entire environment gets copied into the process when it gets created - there is no "access event" to log.

One alternative would be to reverse-engineer the application (disassemble the code and see what parts of the environment it accesses). You might also be able to determine the names of the environment variables it accesses by looking at the strings in the file.